# Azure RDP hangs in few seconds

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp

Windows Azure, RDP for web/worker roles configured successfully. All works fine, I can connect to servers via RDP. I can see logon screen, desktop and so on. But after 3..10 seconds everything freezing. It's seems like disconnect. After reconnection it's all the same: I can work for 3..10 seconds. What should I do to fix it?

**Solution:**
This trouble was because of restarting. So before connecting via RDP try to stabilize node first :)

Comment: Sounds like your instance my be restarting.  I would suggest opening a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the role stay in a running state? I have RDP'ed into many instances of both Web and Worker roles and I have not seen this behavior.

Do you have any other details that you can share? Have you installed/modified anything as a Startup task that might be causing an issue? Have you tried from another client computer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a connection problem. I suggest you contact with the MS support, give them your subscription ID and deployment ID, then the MS will go to your machine to verify deeply.